# Magento 1.9.2.1 (after upgrade): Fatal error by saving product

Tags: magento, nginx

I did upgrade on my Magento shop from 1.8.1 to 1.9.2.1 - almost everything worked well. Only saving products ends with a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote::markQuotesRecollectByAffectedProduct() in /usr/share/nginx/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Observer.php on line 135
```

The function is definitely there under /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php

On the server is nginx 1.4.6 with PHP 5.5.9 and MySQL 5.5.44

- /var/cache/* and /var/session/* was cleared
- cache is also disabled
- I did also reindex

any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Damian

Comment: Check this file also  \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Observer.php

Comment: Do you have a module overriding this Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote in local or community folder?

Comment: @NicolasD good point - there was a file /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who might have this problem again:

> Magento uses an override of core files in local folder, and also in
>   community. So have a look at these folders also even if you called a
>   Mage class.